# Docker- How to Dockerize existing tomcat based Application with Directory Structure

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker, I am trying to dockerize existing tomcat based application with  below structure.[Directory strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf2gs.png)
ProductHomeDir
    |
    |
    |----Tomcat
    |       |
    |       |---webapp
    |               |
    |               |---feature.war
    |               |---support.war
    |
    |
    |----versionDir
    |
    |----ConfDir
    |
    |----log4j.properties

is it possible to create docker image for above structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can copy all the ProductHomeDir into the docker container  using COPY command in dockerfile https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy 
then use CMD in dockerfile to execute scripts inside that container